# can any one help me in this script?

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #conten';
        $('#conten').load(toLoad)

    }   

});

$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #conten';
    $('#conten').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#conten').append('<span id="load"></span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#conten').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#conten').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

the problem now i need to load javascripts code after loading content with ajax 
how can i use Ajax callback method such as the one in jQuery's ajax() method to define what to execute when the request finishes.???

what about adding this function ???

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "product.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('Conten').html(msg);
            $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: where is your ajax() method call ?

Comment: Perhaps just pass the function as the callback to `.load`? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: The ajax method call is being executed by .load().  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Take the () off of showNewContent() in your .load() arguments.  In other words, change your code from this:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#conten').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
```

to this:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#conten').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)
}
```

Once the `.load()` operation is complete, `showNewContent()` will be called.

Comment: the page which load content with ajax have scripts ..... its working very well but when calling with ajax the scripts stopped